# difference between using timespan or integer value representing the timespan in c#

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I have a code where I am calculating some intervals between dates, and to do that I have a defined interval time that I add to one date, to do that I see 2 ways, but I don't understand the difference, for me they are same :

```
var timespan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
var d1 = new DateTime(2010, 1, 1, 8, 0, 15);

var newDateWithTimeSpan = d1.Add(timespan);
var newDateWithSeconds = d1.AddSeconds(5);

Console.WriteLine(newDateWithTimeSpan);
Console.WriteLine(newDateWithSeconds);
```

Comment: Both add 5 seconds, why would you expect a different result?

Comment: One reason for using a dedicated type is clarity.

Comment: You could also do `var timespan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)`.  Also with `TimeSpan` you can do `d1 + timespan`.  Just multiple ways to do stuff to allow for more flexibility.

Comment: You can give that magic number 5 a meaning by creating a timespan object if you give it a meainingful name (e.g. playerReactionLimit). You can also re-use the timespan object throughout your code if that ever becomes helpful, and if you need to change the interval you'd only have to change it in the Timespan constructor instead of everywhere you used the "magic number" 5.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there's no difference between the two ways you're computing the new `DateTime` value. There are often multiple ways of expressing the same intent, particularly with `DateTime`. (You could have used `d1 + timespan` as another option, for example.)

While this isn't the *actual* implementation, you can *imagine* that `AddSeconds` is implemented like this:

```
public DateTime AddSeconds(double seconds) =>
    this.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));
```

It's just a convenience method.

I'd argue that using [`TimeSpan.FromSeconds`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.fromseconds?view=netframework-4.8) in your code is a clearer way of expressing "I want to create a `TimeSpan` that represents 5 seconds" but that's a slightly separate matter.